# Mysql Query Select two tables

Tags: mysql

I need to select all ids of a table that are in another table, but can contain more words. 
example:

`tab1`

```
Hello 
Helloo
Hellooo
Helloooo
```

`tab2`

```
Hello
```

---

The result i need is:

Name: Hello

Count: 4

---

I need to do something like:

```
select count(*) as counted, id from tab1 where id like "helo%"
```

But the `where` clause need to be the ID's from the tab2 plus % at the end.

---

Table1:

```
`ID`: hello
`ID`: hello1
`ID`: hello2
`ID`: hello3
`ID`: hello4
`ID`: hello5
`ID`: yelo5
```

Table2:

```
`ID`: hello
`ID`: yelo
```

Now, what i need is to count and show like this:

`ID`: hello | count: 6

`ID`: yelo | count: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like This

```
select t1.ID,count(*) from tab1 t,tab2 t1 where t.ID like 
CONCAT('%',t1.ID, '%') group by t1.na
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6b58/2)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tab1 as Count_1
WHERE id LIKE '%hello%'

UNION

SELECT count(*) from tab2 as Count_2
WHERE id LIKE '%yelo%' 
GROUP BY id;
```

**RESULT**

```
COUNT(*)
6
1
```

So I think you're trying to COUNT the number of times a ID matching 'hello ... ' appears in Table1 and the number of times an ID matching 'yelo ..' appears in Table2.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it is not what i am looking for. take a look at my updated question

Comment: @user3936835 - Can you update your answer a little further, just to show the column headings from your database. Just the ones required for the MYSQL query? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
      SELECT count(*) FROM tab1 as Count
            LEFT JOIN tab2
            ON tab1.id=tab2.id
            WHERE column like '%Hello%'
```